# publish the C# project with configuration file

Tags: c#, wpf, config, publish

I want to publish the C# project,Visual Studio 2019 ,WPF.

First, application publish;
Second, install the application;
Third, a window pops up after the application installation is complete, showing an error: "An error occurred while loading the configuration file"

I want to put the configuration file in the publish application.

[Code in Visual Studio 2019 WPF][2]

(MainWindow.cs)

private void MainWindow_OnContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //  loading the configuration file
            try
            {
                **Config = RimageConfig.LoadFromFile("config.json");**
            }
            catch
            {
                ShowError**("An error occurred while loading the configuration file", Close);**
                return;
            }

***(config.json)***
{
  "Rk": 0.3167,//
  "Rb": -1.6349,
  "Rg": 8.6982,
  "Rt": 200,
  //"CLeft": 655, //655
  "CLeft": 520, //655
  "CTop": 120,
  "CWidth": 2350,
  "CHeight": 2300,
  "Pa": 100,
  "Pb": 30,
  //"Pa": 255,
  //"Pb": 0,
}

Comment: can you please clarify what is your intention behind publishing ?

Comment: After "publish" was installed and installed on other computers, running the software, I got the error "Loading configuration file wrong".

Comment: So I understand, you have created your wpf app and I assume it works on its own and then you right click and publish. And what are you installing on other computers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting "Copy to Output Directory" property to either "Copy always" or "Copy if newer". To do that in Visual Studio 2019:

- Go to solution explorer
- Navigate to your config file
- Right-click on it
- Properties
- Select desired "Copy to Output Directory" value

This should ensure, that when you use Publish method configs will be copied to publishing directory.

EDIT:
As Corentin pointed out, in my original answer I missed the fact that you are using ClickOnce. In that case you have to go to file properties and set "Build Action" to `Content`. Then go to `Project -> Properties -> Publish`, click on `Application Files...` and make sure, that Publish Status and Download Group for you configs are set to `Include` and `(Required)` respectively.

Comment: Anecdotally, I've encountered issues with the "Copy if newer" option, where it would break and not copy a newer file anymore until I restarted VS. As that leads to an unclear debugging hell, I often simply put it to "Copy always" to avoid the issue altogether. Unless your file is unreasonably large, there shouldn't be any significant drawback from it.

Comment: Thanks, but my Application Files ... that Publish Status did not see my configs. I don't know why

Comment: Did you set your config Build Action to Content? If yes, then try checking "Show All Files" at the bottom of "Application Files..." dialog.

Comment: Can  I add icons to my application when publishing?

Answer (score 0):

A configuration file should probably not be statically defined at compile-time, otherwise it defeats its purpose of being editable later without rebuild.

Your application should survive start-up without a valid configuration file, because this file will be edited by end-users and thus contain errors.

If you only need a static configuration file, you could change your configuration file "Build Action" to "Embedded Resource" and load it using `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream()` method. That would mean they would no longer be editable after build though.

You can also have your code create the configuration file on start-up if it doesn't exist and have it filled with default values (for example, by using default values loaded from an embedded configuration file).

Comment: Just because the configuration can be altered after release, doesn't mean that it "defeats the purpose" to provide a default configuration at compile time. That doesn't have to happen using auto-generation, as you might not want an application whose config file has mysteriously disappeared (for whatever reason) to silently generate a new config file and keep on working. It's contextual based on what you want to happen.